# Angular variable in primefaces commandLink

Tags: angularjs, jsf

I have a little issue with passing an angular variable as an argument in the action attribute of a commandlink.
I tried: `action="#{saisieConge.setCongeWithId({{row.congeId}})}"`
and `action="#{saisieConge.setCongeWithId(row.congeId)}"`

Either way, it is not working :( We just start to integrate angular in our web application and change everything from jsf to angular would be to much of work at ounce. That is way I need to find a way to combine the two.

I would like to avoid passing the angular variable as a param or with `f:setPropertyActionListener` which would need to create a variable in my bean.

Thanks !

Comment: Does it work with a normal `h:commandLink`? And why not use angularFaces? Best of both worlds

Comment: No it doesn't work with h:commandlink neither. I don't know angularFaces a lot. We want to use a safe framework that won't disappear or be abandoned some day. AngularJS seems to be a safe way to go. I don't know about AngularFaces.

Comment: So I searched for AngularFaces. One of the requirements is JSF 2.2 and our whole application is using JSF 2.1. We do not want to migrate to 2.2 right now. Isn't there any other way to solve my problem ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I'm sticking with a stable framework that has serverside counterparts of everything and not oneof the currently hot js frameworks